# When in order to prevent someone from getting upset you want to clarify the subject of your words

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, sentence-usage

How to say: the person who I'm talking about is not you, so take no offence?
I have several similar and self-made sentences listed below, but have no any idea which one works correctly in this sense and which one doesn't and what is the best/most common way to convey this message:

> - I wasn't implying that it was you!
> - I wasn't implying you by that.
> - I'm not implying that it is you!
> - I'm not implying you by that.
> - I don't mean that it was you.
> - I don't mean you by that.

Comment: How about "the person who I'm talking about is not you, so take no offence"..  There are no magic words for this particular situation. You just have to make your own sentence.  You could also have used any of the expressions but they are less clear.

Comment: Many thanks @James K. Just I would be appreciative if you let me know the reason why the 6 other examples sound less clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way is similar to your first attempt:

> I was not talking about you. Please take no offense.

Comment: Thank you very much @virolino; but please let me know what is wrong with "I don't mean you by that" and the other self-made sentences of mine?

Comment: Your sentences are not (all) completely wrong, but they are not usual in the English language. I am not expert enough to explain the details :(